# Why isn't outerWidth() working properly at page load?

Tags: jquery, css

I am using some jQuery to add negative margin to the top and left of an element in order to align it centre in a div.

```
        $('.centred').each(function(event) {
            $(this).css({"margin-top": - ( ($(this).outerHeight()/2) ), "margin-left": - ( ($(this).outerWidth()/2) ) });
        });
```

I have set this jQuery to run on page load and on resize, for some reason the margins are incorrect on page load, but if I resize the window they are then correct.

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lighty_46/9N9xL/3/)

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, when your page loads, each `.view_project` has a smaller width than it should, because it is pushed up against the right hand side of it's container, and the sentence is broken making a new line. You can maintain the width by changing the `white-space` property of `.view_project`:

**CSS**

```
.view_project {
    border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Also, there are some improvements you can make to your jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $('.view_project').each(function (event) {
            $(this).css({
                "margin-top": -(($(this).outerHeight() / 2)),
                "margin-left": -(($(this).outerWidth() / 2))
            });
        });
    }).resize();
})
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/9N9xL/6/)

Comment: Nice catch! Just a few update for better handler imho: http://jsfiddle.net/9N9xL/8/

Comment: Thanks oGeez! Couldn't figure it out haha was driving me crazy. That was what my jQuery looked like originally but I broke it up into separate functions because I thought that might have been the issue. Oh and thanks for the updated code @A.Wolff !

Comment: Glad to have helped (: